# php - apache . работают ли те же скрипты на CGİ?

Tags: php, apache, cgi

Всем привет , есть сайт на локальном хостинге , там стоит php как модуль apache . но хостер предлагает php как CGİ , собственно вопрос , я никак понять не могу , будут ли мои скрипты работающие на php (как модуль apache) 
корректно работать и на CGİ ?? 
Знаю что море литературы , но конкретного так и не нашел ничего.

Comment: а разница есть чем интерпретировать php, и собственно какой вы ответ ожидаете да будет,

Comment: ну до этого работал только с libapache2modphp . просто решил перестраховаться , хоть и признаю что вопрос глупый

Comment: Разницы нет интерпретатор один и ни чем не отличаеться, максимум что может быть разность версии.

Comment: Спасибо большое , вопрос возник от того что , на локальном хосте есть файлы у которых права даны только для апача , вот я и спросил у хостеров , они сказали что автоматически права сменятся на пользователя так как FAST - CGİ